# changing background color when text area contains certain word from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to change the documents background color to goodColor if the textArea contains more goodWords than badWords. and visa versa. Also if the same word from an array is entered twice I need it to count as being included twice.

```
    const goodWords = ['happy', 'joyful', 'amazing', 
    'enjoyed', 'fun', 'excited', 'nice', 'funny', 
    'fantastic', 'good', 'calm', 'comfortable', 
    'glad', 'confident', 'kind'];

    const badWords = ['angry', 'sad', 'upset', 
    'defeated', 'embarrassed', 'jealous', 'nervous', 
    'anxious', 'unhappy', 'miserable', 'worst', 
    'bad'];

    const goodColor = 'rgb(225,225,56,20)'
    const badColor = 'rgb(100,100,50,50)'

    textArea.addEventListener('input', function () {
        for (let good of goodWords) {
            if(text.value.includes(good)) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 
    goodColor;
                
            }  
            }
            for(let bad of badWords) {
                if (text.value.includes(bad)) {
                    
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
                }
            }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to break textarea value by words and then count all matches in both arrays. Then you can simply compare them and color bg as you wish.

```
const goodWords = ['happy', 'joyful', 'amazing', 
    'enjoyed', 'fun', 'excited', 'nice', 'funny', 
    'fantastic', 'good', 'calm', 'comfortable', 
    'glad', 'confident', 'kind'];

const badWords = ['angry', 'sad', 'upset', 
    'defeated', 'embarrassed', 'jealous', 'nervous', 
    'anxious', 'unhappy', 'miserable', 'worst', 
    'bad'];

const goodColor = 'rgb(225,225,56,20)'
const badColor = 'rgb(100,100,50,50)'

textArea.addEventListener('input', function () {
    // Exit if textarea contains only spaces or empty
    if (text.value.trim().length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Using regexp break value to array of words
    const words = text.value.match(/\b(\w+)\b/g)
    let goodCount = 0;
    let badCount = 0;

    // Cycle through words
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
        if (goodWords.includes(words[i])) {
             goodCount++;
        }

        if (badWords.includes(words[i])) {
             badCount++;
        }
    }

    if (goodCount > badCount) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
    } else if (goodCount < badCount) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
    } else {
        // Some neutral color
    }
})
```

Comment: You can do a `split` to split at spaces rather than a regex match.

Comment: @Cjmarkham Of course you can, but it also does include `. , -` characters etc.. So some words won't match anymore because of that

Comment: @Cjmarkham  For example, text `hello, I am a human` will split to `['hello,' 'I', 'am' 'a' 'human']`. for example good word `hello` won't match to `hello,`

Comment: how this code run please i went